# how to replace this v-model pattern in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

Migrating my vue application into react. In vue 2, using a v-model on a component was an equivalent of passing a value prop and emitting an input event.

If we wanted to change prop or event names to something different, we would need to add a model option to ChildComponent component.

Here is my vue child component:

```
export default {
      model: {
        prop: 'checked',
        event: 'change'
      },
      props: {
        value: String,
        checked: {
             type: [Boolean, String, Array],
        },
      }
    }
```

In Parent component i am using like this.

```
<ChildComponent :checked="SelectedFiles" />
```

I want to know how to handle this pattern in react hooks. I am not that much familiar with react. Any guidance will be helpful for me.

Comment: There is no equivalent of `v-model` in React. You have to pass props separately.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) react hook.

For example:

```js
export const MyComponent = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    return (
        <input
            type="text"
            value={value}
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Search..."
            onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
        />
    );
};
```